# How to set size of UIScrollView frame programmatically?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview

I am newbie so my question can be really obvious, but I didn't find any solution so far.

I did in IB UIScrollView and connected it with File's Owner.
I would like to set now the frame size of my UIScrollView (named ScrollView).

```
const CGFloat BoardWidth = 320;
const CGFloat BoardHeight = 400;

//I tried this way but 'Expression is assignable' - said Xcode
ScrollView.frame.size.width = BoardWidth;
ScrollView.frame.size.height = BoardWidth;
```

So how can I the easiest set own sizes of ScrollView frame?

Comment: For future reference: by convention in Objective-C, class names start with a capital letter, while class *instances* and scalar values start with a lower case letter. So `scrollView`, `boardWidth`, and would `boardHeight` would be consistent with the convention.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
CGRect scrollFrame = CGRrectMake(x, y, w, h);
ScrollView.frame = scrollFrame;
```

Or if you need only to change the width and height;

```
CGRect scrollFrame;
scrollFrame.origin = ScrollView.frame.origin;
scrollFrame.size = CGSizeMake(w, h);
ScrollView.frame = scrollFrame;
```

**Edit** keeping the center unchanged:

```
CGRect scrollFrame;
CGFloat newX = scrollView.frame.origin.x + (scrollView.frame.size.width - w) / 2;
CGFloat newY = scrollView.frame.origin.y + (scrollView.frame.size.height - y) / 2;
scrollFrame.origin = CGPointMake(newX, newY);
scrollFrame.size = CGSizeMake(w, h);
scrollView.frame = scrollFrame;
```

Comment: Hm... Seems to be fine, but I would like to keep x and y position as I set in Interface Builder.

Comment: Yes, try the second method I suggested. It only changes the width and the height and keeps x and y unchanged. In fact, a CGRect is composed of an origin where x and y are stored, and a size where width and height are stored.

Comment: Okay, okay. Right. Didn't get it at a first glance. But now it resizes the UIScrollView keeping the left-top point. So if I want it always to be center aligned, I have to just align it now, right?

Comment: Yes, the top-left point did not move because that's the origin of the frame (x, y coordinates). Check my edited answer.

Answer (score 5):

you need to do this, for example.

```
ScrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, BoardWidth, BoardHeight);
```

Once done you need also to set `contentSize` property. It's the area that 'extends' behind the frame of your `UIScrollView`.

If you want to scroll only horizontally:

```
ScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(w * BoardWidth, BoardHeight);
```

If you want to scroll only vertically:

```
ScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(BoardWidth, h * BoardHeight);
```

If you want to scroll both horizontally and vertically:

```
ScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(w * BoardWidth, h * BoardHeight);
```

where `w` and `h` are generic values to increment your width and/or your height.

If you want have an horizontal (for example) discrete scroll (e.g. you have some pages with the same dimension of your screen).

```
ScrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
ScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(p * BoardWidth, BoardHeight);
```

where `p` is the number of pages you want to display.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hehe, thanks a lot. I have it wrote already, really the same way. :P

Answer (score 4):

You can do it as below,

```
scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(xOrigin,yOrigin,width,height);
```

If you are looking for content size of scrollview then it as below,

```
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(width,height);
```

Comment: setting the contentSize in this manner the scrollView doesn't scroll.

Answer (score 1):

```
CGRect Frame = ScrollView.frame

Frame.frame.size.width = BoardWidth;
Frame.frame.size.width = BoardWidth;

ScrollView.frame = Frame;
```

Since frame is a structure..you can't set the frame of an object directly.. You will have to make a Cgrect and then manipulate it.

Answer (score 0):

using contentSize property

```
ScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 520);
```

it needs to be bigger than the frame so it actually scrolls.